# Plot pandas dataframe index formatted as Month-Year on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that I want the x axis to show as APR-2018 for example.  The ax.format_xdata line does not do the trick.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {("IVOG",1493510400000):{"Adj_Close":119.2136,"MA(3)":119.2136,"EWMA(3)":119.2136},
        ("IVOG",1496188800000):{"Adj_Close":120.8236,"MA(3)":120.0186,"EWMA(3)":120.0454},
        ("IVOG",1498780800000):{"Adj_Close":120.2736,"MA(3)":120.1036,"EWMA(3)":120.1266},
        ("IVOG",1501459200000):{"Adj_Close":121.7836,"MA(3)":120.5236,"EWMA(3)":120.5832},
        ("IVOG",1504137600000):{"Adj_Close":120.3536,"MA(3)":120.4896,"EWMA(3)":120.5309},
        ("IVOG",1506729600000):{"Adj_Close":124.3336,"MA(3)":121.1303,"EWMA(3)":121.2749}}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index')
print(df)
ax = plt.gca()      # get current axis
df.plot(kind='line',y='Adj_Close', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='MA(3)',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='EWMA(3)', color='green', ax=ax)
print(df.index[0][1])
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y')     # Trying to get APR-2018
plt.xlabel(df.index[0][0])     # Trying to Get the Ticker
_=plt.grid()
_=plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

The second index should be just the date and not time, but it *incorrectly* plots like this:[Incorrect Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfiEr.png)

Comment: Thanks to  nahusznaj for the help on the label!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Of course there are 'prettier' ways, but I have tried to make it so that you can keep your data and original data frame as close as to the original one in your question.

**Edited after comments**: so how about this, just create a new column with the date that you format in whatever shape you want. Then use *set_xticklabels()* passing that column to set the ticks as you want. Also you might want to remove the default plt.xlabel (otherwise you would have below your xticks the name of the indexes).

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# the first part of your code is the same
data = {("IVOG",1493510400000):{"Adj_Close":119.2136,"MA(3)":119.2136,"EWMA(3)":119.2136},
    ("IVOG",1496188800000):{"Adj_Close":120.8236,"MA(3)":120.0186,"EWMA(3)":120.0454},
    ("IVOG",1498780800000):{"Adj_Close":120.2736,"MA(3)":120.1036,"EWMA(3)":120.1266},
    ("IVOG",1501459200000):{"Adj_Close":121.7836,"MA(3)":120.5236,"EWMA(3)":120.5832},
    ("IVOG",1504137600000):{"Adj_Close":120.3536,"MA(3)":120.4896,"EWMA(3)":120.5309},
    ("IVOG",1506729600000):{"Adj_Close":124.3336,"MA(3)":121.1303,"EWMA(3)":121.2749}}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index')

# first let's give a name to the indexes
df.index.names = ['ivog', 'timestamp']

# then create a new column with a datetime object
# (formatted to microseconds as your data seems to be)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1], 
unit='ms')

# now let's change the date to the format you want
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y %B"))


print(df)

# plot the data just like you were doing
ax = plt.gca()      # get current axis
df.plot(kind='line',y='Adj_Close', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='MA(3)',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='EWMA(3)', color='green', ax=ax)

# Now the x-axis label should be what you wished for
ax.set_xticklabels(df['date'])
plt.xlabel('Your x axis label') 
plt.ylabel('Your y axis label')
plt.title('My Awseome Plot')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Comment: This may get me closer but let me clarify.  The label as IVOG was okay.  I want the xticks as the date in the form APR-2018.

Comment: @KeithW you mean you want the IVOG label in the x_ticks labels? That is, on the x axis you want [(IVOG, APR-2018), (IVOG, MAY-2018), ... ] etc

Comment: Just[(APR-2018),(MAY-2018)]

Comment: @KeithW how about now? I just set the rotation to 45 as I think is more readable.

Comment: @KeithW this works fine for me. If it does for you as well please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Tommy. This does work for me.  I cannot vote yet but I did mark the answer as correct.  I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: FYI I had to change one of the commands to get rid of a SettingWithCopyWarning to:    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.date().strftime("%b-%Y"))